# Is there a reason that Selenium tests would act differently on Ubuntu vs Mac OSX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a project with a partner and we both are using different Operating Systems. All of our files, including the `Gemfile`are under version control. Previously, I had written tests in `Rspec` with `Capybara` and `selenium-webdriver`. These tests opened Firefox and performed simple actions, passed, and closed the browser.

A few unrelated changes to the layout concerning `flash[:success]` and now, with both of us updated to the HEAD, the tests pass on my machine, but fail on his.

His browser is not loading the modal box from the before block `click_link "Edit"` therefore when the test tries to fill in a form, the fields are still hidden and not accessible.

I attempted to wait for the box, thinking it may be filling in the fields too soon :

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { page.driver.browser.find_element(:css, "div#edit_news_container").displayed? == true }
```

Instead I get a timeout, and the tests still fail.

However, they work beautifully on my machine... what's going on here?

Comment: it's possible you're having a browser issue, rather than an operating system issue. are the two of you using the same version of firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of the layout changes, it's likely you're having a browser issue rather than an operating system issue. Are the two of you using the same version of Firefox? If not, changing his version to yours may allow him to load the modal again.

Comment: One we both updated to the latest Firefox version, the tests passed! Thank you, anyaMairead